# When a company launches a new product do they "come out" with a new product or do they "come up" with a new product?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

When a company launches a new product do they **"come out"** with a new product or do they **"come up"** with a new product?

Comment: You'd also often hear "bring out" (or "brought out") in the context of product launches, e.g. *"It only seems like last week that Apple brought out their latest iPhone, the iPhone X."* — [Apple has revealed its latest iPhone patent — *ShortList*](https://www.shortlist.com/tech/apple-has-revealed-its-latest-iphone-patent/379420). (Same meaning as "come out [with]")

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To ***come up*** with something is to invent it, think of it, or create it.

> "That's a great idea, how did you come up with it?"

To ***come out*** with something, in that context (others are quite different) is to announce it. For the product to *come out* is for it to be released.

> Acme Co surprised everyone when they came out with their latest offering, dehydrated tornadoes.
>
> Super Zombie Nazi Killfest comes out on the 30th of February.

Comment: Can you give me example phrases?

Comment: @Kaique: Done, edited into the answer.

Comment: Too bad you didn't post your last example 3 ½ days ago.

Comment: For those who didn't get the reference: https://vimeo.com/236283556 (Acme Tornado Seeds, just add water))

Comment: Acme overhyped those dehydrated tornadoes - it was just a bunch of hot air.

Answer (score 11):

Both could apply depending on context. To "come up with" a new product implies that you have created or invented a new thing, regardless of whether it's actually available for purchase.

> The engineers at Wilson Widgets have come up with a new kind of widget that should make them millions once it's finished.

To "come out with" a new product means that the product has been released and is available for people to buy.

> Wilson Widgets has finally come out with their new widget. It's available in three colors: green, red, and puce.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, English is a language of obfuscation and prepositions.  While the prepositions purport to clarify, the clarification is only to the natives!

A short story might help:

> Chuck's sister **came up** with the idea of having a surprise party at the lake, but, being a secret from Chuck, we couldn't **come out** with it, until we had the party!

Here's an example that I tangled with last month that might give an idea of the full scope of the problem of multi-meaning prepositions.  [Merriam Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down), the on-line version of what many of us grew up with in Tulsa Public Schools, says, about the preposition **"Down"**:

> **down** preposition
>   Definition of *down* (Entry 2 of 9)
>   : down (see [DOWN entry 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down#h1)) along, around, through, toward, in, into, or on
>
> > - fell down the stairs
> > - write down the phone number
> > - down the years
> > - grew up down the block from each other
> > - pacing up and down the room

My annotations:

> **down** preposition
>   Definition of *down* (Entry 2 of 9)
>   : down (see [DOWN entry 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/down#h1)) along, around, through, toward, in, into, or on  [Omits down, descending as preposition definition.]  [Omits down, engraved in concrete.]
>
> > - fell down the stairs [bad example, because stairs go down, an omitted definition.]  [Joe had a cavity, so his dentist pointed out that Joe fell down brushing his teeth.  Meaning "through."  Begs whether "fell" or "fail" is meant in spoken English.]
> > - write down the phone number  [Uses omitted definition.]
> >       down the years [The phrase I've always heard is "down through," so perhaps this is a newer definition.]
> > - grew up down the block from each other  [Good.  Meaning "around."]
> > - pacing up and down the room [Good.  Meaning "through."]

I'm a native speaker with the advantage of hearing little but very good English at home for my first ten years.  So I'm very sympathetic to the problem.  But, perhaps, not much help!

Perhaps Merriam-Webster will either chime in with what they are thinking, or update the on-line Dictionary!

Comment: Lexemes like *come out* and *come up* are considered idioms which means their constituents are not to be analyzed on their own. In other words, the meaning of the whole is different from the meaning of the sum of its parts. : )

Comment: Relevant to the question, you're missing "come down with", which generally means to catch an illness, e.g. "John came down with the flu last week so he had to stay home."

Answer (score 2):

In most scenarios like this, "come out with" is reserved for occasions when the product is released into the open market. "Come up with" is usually when something is discovered/invented. For example, Disney came up with the idea for their movie "The Incredibles 2" long before they came out with it (released it).